# How to trigger CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I am new to CSS but do know the basics, I want to trigger this animation by using a button. I cannot get it to work.

I used a couple of examples here in Stackoverflow, Jquery, Jscript, but none seem to refer to the @keyframes .

I see more about referring to an animation via classes and removing classes (As I understand this way to restart the animation by removing the element). I tried switching it to classes.

I also then wonder what is best practise?

What is the best way? I thought it would be simple, but I was mistaken.....

I have CSS like so:

```
#test {
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
width: 50px;
height: 0px;
background: maroon;
position: absolute;
animation-name: example;
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-delay: 0s;

}
 @keyframes example {
 from { transform: translateY(200px)}
  to {height: 200px; background-color: teal;}
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question (including HTML) - otherwise it's hard to tell *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: Basically this is all the code, it refers to a div with the id test. The animation I want to have it work on click.

Comment: but where is the `div` and the `button`? do you get any errors? all those factors come to play

Comment: I removed it, I dont seem to be able to get it to work. Thats why I only showed the CSS. The answer below seems to work here ! So I attempting this ! But I am doing something wrong

Comment: exactly! if you remove what you have done, how are we to help you fix it? we can only *guess* at what the answer might look like at this point but not really be able to tell you why your code is not working

Comment: Because I dont want to make it longer then necessary. I removed my code and have been searching ever since. I did not even have the code anymore. If I had it I could have posted it. I did not even know where to start anymore. It was a div and this css, thats all.  I did not expect a simple animation button was such a hassle ! But the question has been answered. Next time I will makes sure I will post my last attempt. Thank you :)

Comment: I appreciate that you wanted to keep it short

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the issue you described with your CSS.

See sample below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test-btn").on('click', function() {
    $("#test").addClass('animation');
  });
});
```

```css
.animation {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 0px;
  background: maroon;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: translateY(200px)
  }
  to {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: teal;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="test-btn">Animate</button>
<hr/>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the Jquery edition of the answer. I am learning a lot by this. But I apparently have made a mistake ? I should have posted everything? I thought I did it right. But previously a commenter already mentioned I should post the html. Thing is, it was only a div and a button with no referal to a code anymore.

Comment: Oh that was you as well :)

Comment: @Codelly the idea is to post the minimal code necessary to reproduce the issue.  Welcome to StackOverflow! I am glad both answers were helpful

Comment: Okay will do next time ! Thank you much !

Comment: @Codelly you are welcome. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

In case you decide to scrap jQuery *(or you have to work without it)*, in order to toggle the CSS animation on your `#test` element **using vanilla JavaScript**, separate your animation-related CSS properties into a class:

```
.animate {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

Then toggle *(add/remove)* the `.animate` class on the `#test` element:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (isAnimating) {
    element.classList.remove('animate');
    button.innerHTML = 'Add animation';
  } else {
    element.classList.add('animate');
    button.innerHTML = 'Remove animation';
  }

  isAnimating = !isAnimating;
});
```

```js
var element = document.getElementById('test');
var button = document.getElementById('toggle');
var isAnimating = false;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (isAnimating) {
    element.classList.remove('animate');
    button.innerHTML = 'Add animation';
  } else {
    element.classList.add('animate');
    button.innerHTML = 'Remove animation';
  }
  
  isAnimating = !isAnimating;
});
```

```css
#test {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 0px;
  background: maroon;
  position: absolute;  
}

.animate {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

#toggle {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: translateY(200px)
  }
  to {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: teal;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<button id="toggle">Add animation</button>
```

Comment: Thank you that is a very clear explanation, I will also learn the Jquery version of it. I am trying it out now. It seems to have some issues at my side. But it works here on the site. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: You're welcome! If you have further issues, please post it on SO, but keep up the rules regarding the [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ;)

Comment: Thank you!!!  I had to put this around the code : window.onload=function(){ the code you provided } Because it gave me the Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. I have not heard of Vanilla Jscript, I assumed its not the best way :) But it is so nice to see it work. I will improve the code now !

Comment: Keep up the good work @Codelly!